# Cannot install Posgresql on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Typing `sudo apt-get install postgresql-11` gives me error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-11 : Depends: postgresql-client-11
                 Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.3~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sysstat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How Can I solve this error and finally install Postgres on my ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

To solve the unmet dependencies error just add latest PostgreSQL apt repository

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
$ wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then just fire update command

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

After that in your case install postgresql-11

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-11
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it. Went to
https://packages.debian.org/buster/postgresql-11
and downloaded the package for me was `libicu63`
then I installed it manually.
the run `sudo apt install postgresql`  to install the latest postgresql.

Check the postgresql version `psql -V`

For me this is the result:
`psql (PostgreSQL) 15.0 (Debian 15.0-1.pgdg100+1)`

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Try to run that command, and let me know what you see. Apparently postgres requires some packages that you haven't installed yet

Comment: It doesn't work. ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-11 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-11
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.``` I cant install any postgres 9/10/11 on ubuntu 19.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088444/install-postgresql-9-4-on-ubuntu-18-04  -first answer helped. I just need to add apt repository to Ubuntu 19.